# Numpy shared_memory array resetting with zeros inside Pool

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, shared-memory, python-3.8

I am trying to share a large 3 dimensional numpy array with a process `Pool` so as to perform some operations with slices of said large array.
In my `main`:

```py
_dtype = np.dtype('float64')
n_rotations, n_coords, n_points = 7000, 3, 25600
shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(
    create=True, size=n_rotations * n_coords * n_points * _dtype.itemsize)
rotations_name = shm.name
coordinates = np.ndarray(
    (n_rotations, n_coords, n_points), dtype=_dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
coordinates = rotations @ ellipsoid
print(coordinates.shape)  # outputs (n_rotations, n_coords, n_points)

chunks = [(rot_idx, rotations_name,
            args.output, (n_rotations, n_coords, n_points), max_rad)
            for rot_idx in range(n_rotations)]
pool = Pool(args.processes)
_res = pool.starmap_async(gen_features, chunks).get()
```

Here `gen_features` is defined as follows:

```py
def gen_features(idx: int, buf_name: str, _dir: str,
                 rot_dims: tuple, max_rad: int):
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=buf_name)
    rotations = np.ndarray(rot_dims, dtype=np.dtype('float64'), buffer=shm.buf)
    print(rotations)  # here the np array has become zero-filled for some reason
    del rotations, _
    shm.close()
    return idx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending almost an hour of debugging, turns out you have to "copy" the data, as mentioned under [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html#multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory.size) section:

> ```py
> b[:] = a[:]  # Copy the original data into shared memory
> ```

So basically, this

```py
coordinates[:] = rotations @ ellipsoid
```

instead of

```py
coordinates = rotations @ ellipsoid
```